# How do I unbind events on elements that are not the last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a form input that appends an empty input field to the end of a series, only if the value of the previous field is true.
I'v gotten pretty far but I'm having trouble re-binding the last element.

```js
function removeEmpty(){
  $('p:last').remove()
}
function init(){
  
   $('p:last input').focus(function(event){
   $(event.target).closest('p').append("<p class=''><label>middlename: </label><input></input></p>")
   init()
  })

 
  $('p:last input').blur(function(event){
    console.log($(event.target).val())
      if(!$(event.target).val()){
        removeEmpty()
      }

  })
}
init()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="first">
<label>middlename: </label><input></input>
</p>
```

Comment: when you say the value of the previous field is true, do you mean literally 'true' or has content?

Comment: p that is not the last: `jQuery('p').filter(':not(:last)')`

Comment: FYI input is void element, there is no closing tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `event delegation` instead.

Instead of using this:

```
$('p:last input').focus(...); 
$('p:last input').blur(...);
```

you could use this:

```
$('body').on("focus","p:last input", function() { ... });
$('body').on("blur","p:last input", function() { ... });
```

I've updated your code:

```
function removeEmpty(){
  $('p:last').remove()
}
function init(){

    $("body").on('focus','p:last',function(event){
       var target = $(event.target);

       target.closest('p').append("<p class=''><label>middlename: </label><input></input></p>");

       target.one("blur",function() {
           if(!target.val()) {
             removeEmpty();
           }
       });
    })

 }
 init()
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/
and http://api.jquery.com/one/

I guess this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/baL5ge30/1/) is what you want!

Comment: The one handler is a new one for me. Looks like I need to read up on early and late binding too. thanks for the help, Now I'm going to try and collapse empty inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using `append` instead of after... Use this

```
  $(event.target).closest('p')
  .after("<p class=''><label>middlename:</label><input></input></p>")
   init()
```

In addition, To select the p that is not the last: use `jQuery('p').filter(':not(:last)')`

And the `removeEmpty` must be somthing like

```
function removeEmpty(){
  jQuery('p').filter(':not(:first)').find('input').each(function(){
     if(!($(this).value)) $(this).closest('p').remove();
  });
}
```

The complete code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpRrGR)